# c++ заполнение массивов. Core dumped ошибка

Tags: c++, массивы, vector

Как в c++ получить данные для векторов с использованием конструктора for.

```
vector<int> d;
vector<int> c;
int n;
cin >> n;
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
    сin >> d[i] >> c[i];}
```

выводит ошибку core dumped

данные нужно принять:

```
5
4 4
3 3
2 6
3 8
6 1
```

Я пока что начинающий в этом деле, если поможете горячее вам спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1.

```
d.resize(n);
c.resize(n);
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    сin >> d[i] >> c[i];
```

Вариант 2.

```
for(int x, y, i=0; i < n; i++)
{
    сin >> x >> y;
    d.push_back(x);
    c.push_back(y);
}
```

Comment: №3  int n; cin >> n;  vector<int> d(n), c(n);...